# (exception Resources$NotFoundException))ListView.layoutChildren() line: 1596

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a list with a custom List item cell in a completely programatic way (without using any xml). I am running into below error. After several hours of searching on the web, I am writing this as my first question on Stack Overflow.

Appreciate your inputs on this & any suggestions on how to better handle Android programming without using the R.*.xml

**On running this code, I get the below error:**

(Suspended (exception Resources$NotFoundException))

ListView.layoutChildren() line: 1596

ListView(AbsListView).onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 1112

ListView(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 6569

FrameLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 333 
...

**Code:**

public class MyList extends ListActivity{

```
static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = 
    new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

//CUSTOM LIST

```
    LinearLayout mainLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    ListView myListView=new ListView(this);
    mainLayout.addView(myListView);


    LinearLayout ListItemLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    TextView author = new TextView(this);
    TextView price = new TextView(this);
    ListItemLayout.addView(title);
    ListItemLayout.addView(author);
    ListItemLayout.addView(price);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        this,
        list,
        ListItemLayout.getId(),
        new String[] {"title","author","price"},
        new int[] {ListItemLayout.getChildAt(0).getId(),ListItemLayout.getChildAt(1).getId(),ListItemLayout.getChildAt(2).getId()}
    );     
    populateList();
    setListAdapter(adapter);  

}

private void populateList() {
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("title",
"Professional Android ");
    map.put("author", "Meier");
    map.put("price", "$54.99");
    list.add(map);
    map = new HashMap();
    map.put("title","Android 2");
    map.put("author", 
"Sayed");
    map.put("price", "$48.98");
    list.add(map);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. `SimpleAdapter` requires a resource id from a layout defined in xml. It also requires the resource ids of the `TextView`s that it will be populating. This is because it uses `LayoutInflater#inflate` to create the containing `View` and then `ViewGroup#findViewById` to get the reference to the `TextView`s that will display the data.

If you want to do all your layout in code including that of the `Adapter` you will have to create your own custom `Adapter` class. You can do this by extending `BaseAdapter` and overriding `getView` at a minimum.

Comment: Worked perfectly after creating a custom Adapter. Thanks Qberticus!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of your SimpleAdapter requires an id from your ListItemLayout but it doesn't have one (I guess the Android fall back is to check the R file), so assign it an id in your code.

Comment: Added setId for both ListItemLayout and the TextViews. Still getting the same error..

        LinearLayout ListItemLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
        ListItemLayout.setId(1002);
        TextView title = new TextView(this);
        title.setId(1003);
        TextView author = new TextView(this);
        author.setId(1004);
        TextView price = new TextView(this);
        price.setId(1005);
        ListItemLayout.addView(title);
        ListItemLayout.addView(author);
        ListItemLayout.addView(price);